# Dollar ($) sign and commas in thousands for a number with String.Format()

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

Trying to format a number **5620000** to **$5,620,000**

```
string html = string.Format("$ {0:n0}", 5620000)
```

Is it possible to do with string.Format function ?

Comment: Your source needs to be a number, not a string, convert it first.

Comment: So now you have edited to use an int, it should be working fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @DavidG problem with result $ 5.620.000 its returning, we want comma.

Comment: Then you need to write this in the question, not wait an hour to add it in the comments. At 2k+ rep you should know this by now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [overload of `ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d830955a(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an `IFormatProvider` as argument and specify that the number is currency.

```
var value = 5620000;
value.ToString("C", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
```

EDIT

As @Uwe Keim pointed out you can also use the [`String.Format()` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx) that does this:

```
String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", 5620000)
```

Comment: `String.Format` also has an overload with `IFormatProvider `, e.g. [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906224(v=vs.110).aspx).